# cv2.stereoRectifyUncalibrated : error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.size == dst.size && src.channels() == dst.channels() in function 'cvConvertScale'

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to use stereoRectifyUncalibrated in OpenCV 4.1.1. The code is as follows.

```
points1 = np.array([[2566, 542], [2567, 848], [2569, 947],
               [3154, 452], [3158, 934], 
               [4061, 332], [4069, 576]])

points2 = np.array([[277, 471], [290, 774], [296, 868],
                [794, 393], [816, 830], 
                [1472, 310], [1480, 510]
])

F, mask = cv2.findFundamentalMat(points1, points2)
ret, H1, H2 = cv2.stereoRectifyUncalibrated(points1, points2, F, imgSize=(4112, 1200))
```

It generates an error as follows.

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
---> 11 ret, H1, H2 = cv2.stereoRectifyUncalibrated(points1, points2, F, imgSize=(4112, 1200))
error: OpenCV(4.1.1) /home/hao/workspace/opencv/modules/core/src/convert_c.cpp:112: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.size == dst.size && src.channels() == dst.channels() in function 'cvConvertScale'
```

As the document says "points2   The corresponding points in the second image. The same formats as in findFundamentalMat are supported." (https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gaadc5b14471ddc004939471339294f052). I have no idea what's going on. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

You simply don't have enough points.

Long answer:

As you have only 7 points, the function findFundamentalMat does not return a single 3x3 matrix but 3 3x3 matrices.

The exception is actually thrown in stereoRectifyUncalibrated when the function tries to convert F into a 3x3 matrix, but fails because src.size == dst.size is not true.

Now why did findFundamentalMat returned 3 matrices?

In the documentation, the number of points should be:

> CV_FM_7POINT for a 7-point algorithm. N=7
>   CV_FM_8POINT for an 8-point algorithm. N≥8
>   CV_FM_RANSAC for the RANSAC algorithm. N≥8
>   CV_FM_LMEDS for the LMedS algorithm. N≥8

The default is CV_FM_RANSAC and I guess that the code silently switched to the method CV_FM_7POINT (only possible case with 7 points)

About this method, the documentation of findFundamentalMat says:

> The function calculates the fundamental matrix using one of four methods listed above and returns the found fundamental matrix. Normally just one matrix is found. But in case of the 7-point algorithm, the function may return up to 3 solutions ( 9×3 matrix that stores all 3 matrices sequentially).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. It helped a lot.